# Shadow on all the page except an input with Angular 4

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I have an angular 4 application with an input and I want to focus on this input when clicking on it. So I want to darken all the page except the input on focus. So I tried to add a div with a black background and 50% opacity.

But the input is always below the div whereas it has a `z-index` higher.

This is my html code :

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div id="blanket"></div>
```

The CSS code of the blanket :

```
#blanket {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

In the component :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="z-index: 2000000 !important;background-color: #fff" (focus)="focusOnInputName()" (blur)="blurOnInputName()" >
```

And the 2 functions :

```
focusOnInputName(){
    console.log('focus');
    let d = document.querySelector('#blanket');
    this.renderer.setStyle(d, "visibility", "visible");

}

blurOnInputName(){
    console.log('blur');
    let d = document.querySelector('#blanket');
    this.renderer.setStyle(d, "visibility", "hidden");
}
```

When focus or blur, the `blanket div` appears or disappears but the input is always hidden by the "blanket".

How can I do to have what I want?

**EDIT**
I want to do the same thing like the bootstrap modal but on the click on an input.

Comment: that question should have CSS tag

Answer (score 2):

Just add `position: relative` to the input element.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50px;
  border: #00f solid 2px;
}
.container input {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative; /* Add this */
}
.blanket {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <p>Some other text</p>
  <input placeholder="Type something"/>
  <p>Some more text</p>
</div>

<div class="blanket"></div>
```

Comment: Well I run the code snippet, and I see a working input over a full-page dark blanket. Same with my Codepen : https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/vWOxvo. Define `it doesn't work`.

Comment: But the " div blanket" is not on the same level for me. Can it cause the problem ?

Comment: Is it at the same level as the input in my snippet? :)

Comment: And if you hide the blanket and display it when clicking on the input. Does it work ?

Comment: Uh, why wouldn't it? The blanket is at the right place.

Comment: So, in fact, it works if I put the blanket in the same html file. But if I place it like in my example and not in the same file of the input, it doesn't work.

Comment: So, it's not on the all page because it's just in the component. Do you know how I can do it ?

Comment: I fix my problem by using the same thing that for the bootstrap modal : `<bs-modal-backdrop id="blanket" class="modal-backdrop fade in show"></bs-modal-backdrop>`